# What is the source for the Baal Shem Tov’s application of Psalm 122 (1) to a marriage?

Tags: sources-mekorot, wedding, tehilim-psalms, drush, baal-shem-tov

I seem to remember a Dvar Torah from the Baal Shem Tov that reinterprets [the first verse of Psalm 122](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16343/showrashi/true#v1)

> I rejoiced when they said to me, "Let us go to the house of the Lord."

into a dialogue between the bride and the groom in which she says,

I was glad when you said to me, let us build a Jewish house

I would like to find the source.

Comment: It's not this pshat, but they say from - which Galicianer achron's mother? - that where she lived, single women didn't go to shul, only married ones. Thus, "samachti b'omrim LI": when I finally heard someone tell me "harei at mekudeshes LI", then "beis Hashem nelech" - I can go to shul now!

Comment: @Shalom Pearl Benisch attributes that idea to Sarah Schenirer in her biography Carry Me in Your Heart, p. 151-152.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this story](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30171&st=&pgnum=6) (see left column 3 last paragraphs), the mother of the Rebbe Horav Naftoli Ropzcher said it when they took her to Shul, "when I finally heard someone tell me "harei at mekudeshes LI", then "beis Hashem nelech"...". (The story starts on page 4).

Comment: Beautiful. But I heard the story **as in my question** at my Sheva Brochos and someone has reported it to me in the same way.